# Dropdown href="" redirects to index page instead of showing dropdown list

Tags: php, html

Hi I am trying to get a dropdown list to appear when you click a button, problem is that whenever I click the button it goes to the index page instead of showing the list.

However, the button works only on one specific page which is almost identical to the others.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
    <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <?Php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?><span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="welcome.php">User Details</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> -->
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="inc/config/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use javascript:void(0) instead of blank.

```
 <li class="dropdown"> 
   <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <?Php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?><span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="welcome.php">User Details</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> -->
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="inc/config/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Kamani, I did try that but it seems to work on a particular page but then doesn't work when on the subsequent pages.